# Is there an easier way to pair the values from JCheckBox and JTextField instead of using HashMap

Tags: java, swing, collections, hashmap

So my goal is to be able to store the value pair of Grade Level and Amount. Right now, I'm not sure if collections is the best way to solve my problem.

So my GUI looks like this.

[image]

For every one addition of Fee, it may have 1 or more pair of grade level and amount.

So what I did is populate the selected checkboxes to identify which GradeLevel and Amount needs to be inserted to a MANY-to-MANY database table.

Here's how I populated it. Do you have any idea how to possibly reduce the code. Perhaps another way instead of using `Maps`?

```
Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
Integer key = null;
Double value = null;

Component[] comp = jpnlFeeAmount.getComponents();
for (Component c : comp) {
    if (c instanceof JCheckBox) {
        if (((JCheckBox) c).isSelected() && !((JCheckBox) c).getText().equals("Kindergarten")) {
            String glStr = ((JCheckBox) c).getText().replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " "); //takes out all numeric from string 
            String aGradeLevel = glStr.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // removes all whitespace
            if (!aGradeLevel.isEmpty()) {
                int aGradeLevelInt = Integer.parseInt(aGradeLevel);
                switch (aGradeLevelInt) {
                    case 1:
                        key = 1;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade1Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        key = 2;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade2Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        key = 3;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade3Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        key = 4;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade4Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        key = 5;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade5Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        key = 6;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade6Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        key = 7;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade7Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        key = 8;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade8Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        key = 9;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade9Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        key = 10;
                        value = Double.parseDouble(jtfGrade10Amount.getText().trim());
                        break;
                }
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        } else if (((JCheckBox) c).isSelected() && ((JCheckBox) c).getText().equals("Kindergarten")) {
            key = 0;
            value = Double.parseDouble(jtfKindergartenAmount.getText().trim());
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I plan to get the id of gradelevel, perhaps a `getId(int gradelevel)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a new object that holds the information. Would post a full answer but it's 5:31pm and I'm going home now.

Comment: Would [`JLabel:setLabelFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor-java.awt.Component-) and  [`JLabel:getLabelFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#getLabelFor-java.awt.Component-) help? It's not their intended use, but might help.

Comment: Write some classes to represent the data (grades and associated fees).  I would also dynamically build the controls rather than looping through them later.